# Error Adding S3 Log Annotations to K8s Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

We're running k8s 1.10 in AWS EKS.

We're trying to put our load balancer logs into an S3 bucket by adding the required annotations to a service yaml file [as described here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/).

Here's a snippet from our services yaml file.

```
metadata:
    annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-enabled: true
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-emit-interval: 60
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-s3-bucket-name: [our-logs-bucket]
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-access-log-s3-bucket-prefix: [a-prefix]
```

However, whenever we apply the changes, we get the following error:

`error: services "[service name]" could not be patched: cannot convert int64 to string`

We've tried a couple things, including placing the "60" in quotation marks, and using different values for the log-emit-interval. No luck.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried your same config on the newest version of kubernetes and could no longer replicate your error.
My guess is that you needed to both quote the "true" and the "60" as annotations are supposed* to be strings, and true might have gotten parsed differently by YAML. Your config itself works fine for me, thank you for the template honestly.
Hope you got this working OK.